# Difference between an Instance and Object in Java

Tags: java

In Java, what is the difference between instance of a class and Object of a class.

For a `class A`,  Take a look :

line 1 : `A a;  // Declaring a reference variable of class A`

Line 2 :  `a = new A();// Instantiating an object of class A`

So....can the line 2 also be :  // Instantiating an instance of class A

which mean Instance and Object are absolutely the same thing ?

Please give an objective answer than subjective.

Comment: They are the same thing.  An object is an instance of a class (and there's nothing else in Java to have an instance of).  In other languages you might have an instance of a "struct" or some such, but Java only has "class"

Comment: (But just to confuse things, "Object" with a capital O is a class -- the mother of all classes.)

Comment: So what is the definition of instance and object. "An object is an instance of a class" ...can you please elaborate ? What is the difference between and instance and object then ?

Comment: To be simple, "an object" and "an instance" are the same in Java, just different expression.

Comment: *instance* means ***a single occurance***. This is why an object would be an *instance* of the class.

Comment: @VinceEmigh ...So an instance and object is same ?  No difference at all.   An object is an instance of the class .... or an Instance is an object of a class....same ?

Comment: An object is an instance of a class. An **instance of a class** is an object. *instance* means "a single occurance", in both programming and the real world. When you hear "instance" in programming, its USUALLY referring to an instance of a class (which yes, is an object), but an instance is an abstract term, and could be a single occurance of anything (which in this case, is a class)

Answer (score 3):

Line 1 declares a variable, it doesn't reference anything, though, its value is null.

Line 2 creates a new object and assigns it to the variable `a`.

An object is an instance of a class. A class is something used to create objects, an object is something created (instantiated) using that class as a template.

"instance" means a specific occurrence of something. For instance, you could talk about database instances, where each instance is an installation in a specific place on a specific server somewhere. Likewise with objects, an instance is a specific member of a category.

Comment: So what is the definition of instance and object.    "An object is an instance of a class"   ...can you please elaborate ?    What is the difference between and instance and object then ?

Comment: @Navchetan: i'm unsure what you're asking

Comment: SO..." An object is an instance of a class "....this quote of yours has 3 elements :   1. Class..( A blueprint of an object ...how an object will act/behave/look when born/instantiated) .....2. object...the entity defined by entity 1(class) ....and now in action/alive/born ....3. Instance....???????

Comment: ....So is this correct to say :                                              Home home1 = new Home();  ..... here Home is the class....home1 is the instance .... "new Home()" is the object ?   .....so the reference variable home1 is the instance ??

Comment: home1 is the instance, it's also an object. really there's no difference. "new Home()" is the constructor call that instantiates/constructs/creates the object.

Answer (score 0):

The term "instance of" is used to show you from which classes the specific object origins from. The objects Buddy, Lucky and Sparky are instances of dogs but also instances of animals. So the object itself can be an instance of multiple classes. A cat is also an instance of animals and an instance of cats but not an instance of dogs.

`public abstract class Animals{...}`

`public class Dogs extends Animals{...}`

`public class Cats extends Animals{...}`

Answer (score 0):

The object and the instance are of different stories. It's like asking what is the difference between a Car and an Engine.

Anyway, an object is a representation of a class. A class is the file that you write and save.

Once you use a class and put it into memory, an object is created.

Instantiating is the process of using a class to create an object based on that class and putting it into memory.

```
A a;  // Declaring a reference variable of class A
```

This means you are reserving a variable for a particular object or particular class.

```
a = new A();// Instantiating an object of class A
```

This means that you are using the A.class as your base class to create the object a. And this process is basically Instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Line 1, you declare an variable which type is A, but the variable doesn't have any value, its value is null.

In Line2, you created an object of Class A using new, and assign a reference of that object to variable a, in another words, you assigned a reference of A class's object to the variable a.

a is called the instance of class A, the object it refers to is called the object of A